# ¿cómo incorporar correctamente jdbc sqlite en un proyecto java con vscode?

Tags: java, sqlite, vscode, jdbc

Tenía algo de experiencia en java hace varios años y estoy tratando de retomar el lenguaje usando VSCode, pero estoy teniendo una dificultad con el driver jdbc sqlite que no he logrado resolver ni he encontrado información que me sea útil.

El caso es que estoy tratando de incorporar una base de datos SQLite en el proyecto java, pero no he logrado establecer siquiera la conexión; incluso con un proyecto "limpio" obtengo una de dos respuestas

> Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal App

cuando el driver está en la carpeta lib

o

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:hr.db

cuando está en cualquier otra ubicación.

Sobre el driver, he usado las versiones "sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar" y "sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.1.jar" sin éxito; el jdk es de la versión 17. Tengo la impresión de que es un problema de compatibilidad, pero no he logrado encontrar ninguna información específica al respecto.

El proyecto simplificado que no trae nada más que tres archivos: La base de datos, la clase App con el metodo main() y el driver...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código de la App también está al mínimo:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        conexion();
    }

    public static Connection conexion() {
        Connection conn=null;
        String url ="jdbc:sqlite:hr.db";
        try {
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if(conn!=null){
                System.out.println("Conexón exitosa");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

He buscado información sobre el tema, incluso el sitio de SQLite tiene una artículo sobre su uso en VSCode y, por lo que he leido, se supone que no hace falta nada más y debería funcionar sin problemas, pero no he logrado hacerlo funcionar.

Como comentario quiero agregar que instalé tambien el complemento SQLite de VSCode y, con él, puedo manipular la base de datos sin problemas; pero en el proyecto nada me funciona.

¿Qué estoy omitiendo? o ¿cuál otro puede ser el problema?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

===

Actualizando mi problema, os comento que he bajado la version del jdk a la 11.0.15, para confirmar algún error de compatibilidad. El sistema siempre me ha mostrado la misma versón de java y javac, antes la 17 y ahora la 11. Pero el problema sigue manifestándose idéntico y sigo sin poder saber cuál es la causa.

Yo siento que cuando el driver 'sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar' se coloca en la carpeta lib, destinada a las librerías de mi proyecto; de algún modo toma el control del flujo del programa impidiendo encontrar la clase principal, pero no tengo certeza; **¿hay alguna forma de invocar ese archivo .jar en tiempo de ejecución, cuando ya esté corriendo la clase principal, es decir, dentro del código de esta?**

Comment: Hola buenas tardes se que no viene a la pregunta pero por mi parte prefiero utilizar ides diseñados para soportar java como eclipse o intelliJ, donde hacer la conexión a la base es mas facil, por supuesto que no digo que no se pueda hacer con visual.

Comment: hola, estas omitiendo el sistema de construcción o que vscode no es un IDE. los plugins que hay ahora de java para vscode son incipientes, posiblemente por razones históricas. Tines dos opciones o compilar manualmente y agregar tu libreria en el classpath, o usar u sistema de construccion como maven, gradle, sbt, ant, etc. Un simple editor como vscode no cuenta con las capacidades minimas con las que cuenta un IDE y aun así los IDE por defecto usan ant. Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0):

En la parte donde añades el url debes colocar la dirección del JDBC que de proporciona sqlite, seguido del usuario de la bdd y la contraseña, esto en el caso de que tenga. deberia quedar algo como esto.

```
  public Connection conexion() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombre_bdd", "usuario", "contraseña");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Conexion fallida " + ex);
        }
        return con;
    }
```

Como puedes ver, el url contiene la direccion ip (en mi caso localhost es igual a 127.0.0.1) y el nombre de la BDD. Si no tienes usuario y contraseña, simplemente omitelo.

```
 public Connection conexion() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombre_bb);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Conexion fallida " + ex);
        }
        return con;
    }
```

Yo uso Netbeans y Mysql workbench pero espero y te pueda ayudar esta información. De igual manera encontré esta página que podria ayudarte: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/
Saludos.

Comment: Diana gracias por tu apoyo e interés, te cuento que probé con la ruta completa de la base de datos y me sigue devolviendo el error de que no encuentra la clase App.

Comment: Sobre el enlace que me compartes, ya lo había visto y traté de adaptarlo para usarlo en vsCode, pero no me ayudó; aunque hubo un detalle que me confundió, no me quedó claro si la carpeta connect se crea dos veces, una en c:\sqlite\java\ (paso 2 y 8) y otra en c:\sqlite\ (pasos 3 y 4) o si esto último es un error de transcripción; pero en su momento probé las dos formas (dentro de vsCode) y ninguna funcionó.

Comment: Si se te ocurre alguna otra idea, de verdad te la agradezco; el tema me tiene loco. Ya reinstale el vsCode y todo, pero nada

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que al momento de hacer la BDD debes crear un tipo de conexión con el servidor que creaste, verifica que el puerto que use sea el correcto (usualmente es el 3306) verificar la ip y que sea compatible con windows. 
Tambien podrias revisar en el cmd que la version de java y javac (el jdbc) se la misma.

Comment: Puedes revisar las versiones con los comandos `java -version` y `javac version`

Comment: La  DB no la hice yo, la tengo en carpeta local y no puedo manipular su configuración está abierta sin ususario ni contraseña; pero voy a probar con una creada localmente, tambien voy a comprobar las versiones de java y javac; partí del hecho que eran compatibles y no lo había pensado, gracias. Te estaré contando

Comment: Probé las dos cosas, java y javac tienen la misma versión (antes la 17 y ahora la 11) y la BD creada localmente (SQLite trabaja localmente sin servidor por lo que leí) tampoco funciona, aunque en realidad no parece llegar al punto en que se establece la conexión sino que main() ni siquiera inicia porque no lo encuentra. Sigo atento, gracias